# kivy remove parent and add child new widget

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

guys how to separate child to parent?

`kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivymd.uix.card.MDCard object at 0x000001EBCBFFB0B8>`

it already has a parent `<kivymd.uix.list.MDList object at 0x000001EBCF105B38>`.
I can separate mdcard object and add a new widget.

Comment: If you want to remove a widget (call it `abba`) from its parent, you can do `abba.parent.remove_widget(abba)`

Answer (score 1):

To remove a widget from its parent you have to use `remove_widget` function. If you want to remove all widgets from a parent, you can use `clear_widgets` function. You can check more details [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget).

I would appreciate if you provide some code so that I can correct it